# Incremental column coming from variable in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a variable that comes from a function that returns an integer.

I need to create an incremental column in my dataframe from this integer, how can I do that?

Integer example: 201

Output expected:

| Stores | New column |
| --- | --- |
| Marcos Store | 202 |
| Lais Store | 203 |
| Carol Store | 204 |
| Ana Store | 205 |
| Maria Store | 206 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = 201
df['New column'] = df.index + n + 1
```

Output:

```
         Stores  New column
0  Marcos Store         202
1    Lais Store         203
2   Carol Store         204
3     Ana Store         205
4   Maria Store         206
```

Comment: If you're index isn't nicely numbered like this,  then `df['New column'] = df.reset_index().index + n + 1` would work as well~